# Setting up Angular phonecat application on node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Im newbie to Angular and trying to setup angular phonecat application.

I have downloaded the code from here

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/

and installed a nodejs.

Now, I'm not sure how to map the angular application to run with nodejs.

From other links, I see everyone run a webserver.js file but I don't see anything under the scripts directory.

```
scripts]$ tree .
.
├── private
│   ├── old
│   │   ├── format-json.sh
│   │   ├── goto_step.bat
│   │   ├── goto_step.sh
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── ScrapeData.js
│   │   └── snapshot.sh
│   ├── push-to-github.sh
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── retag.sh
│   ├── test-all.sh
│   └── update-gh-pages.sh
└── update-repo.sh
```

How can I run the application in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page you linked, you are supposed to run `npm start` in the main directory after installing NPM dependencies with `npm install`.

EDIT: After checking their package.json, you can actually just run `npm start`. It will also run dependency installation.